# Cast subqueries in QueryDSL 4

Tags: querydsl

I'm migration an application from QueryDSL 3 to QueryDSL 4 and I did most of the work, but I'm still struggling with two things I'm not able to migrate.

### **.stringValue()**

In QueryDSL 3, I have that:

```
SubQueryExpression<String> uuidsSubQuery = new HibernateSubQuery()
   .from(qEntity)
   .where(qEntity.id.eq(1))
   .unique(qEntity.uuid.stringValue());
```

Column `qEntity.uuid` is of type `UUID` (PostgreSQL database), which is mapped as a `java.util.UUID` in class `QEntity`. However, I use my subquery later in a projection, and I need the subquery to return a `String`, not an `UUID`, that's why I use the `.stringValue()`.

In queryDSL 4, I tried the following:

```
JPQLQuery<String> uuidsSubQuery = JPAExpressions.selectFrom(qEntity)
   .where(qEntity.id.eq(1))
   .select(qEntity.uuid.stringValue());
```

But the method `.stringValue()` is not available. Is there any way to do it?

### **.castToNum() and .divide()**

In QueryDSL 3:

```
NumberExpression<Long> countEntities1 = new HibernateSubQuery().from(qEntity).where(XXXXXX).unique(qEntity.count());

NumberExpression<Long> countEntities2 = new HibernateSubQuery().from(qEntity).where(YYYYYY).unique(qEntity.count()); 

new HibernateUpdateClause(session, qZZZZ)
    .set(
         ZZZZ.count,
         countEntities1.castToNum(BigDecimal.class).divide(countEntities2)
    )
    .execute();
```

But in QueryDSL 4, I did not find a way to apply the `castToNum(BigDecimal.class)` and the `.divide()` operation between my two subqueries. Is there any equivalent?